# How to redirect to external URL in angular from entry menu

Tags: angularjs, angular

In my menu definiton I have something like that:

```
    ...
function routeConf($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state({
        name: 'application.users',
        url: '/users' // in this place I would like to replace with http://google.com
    })
}

    ..
```

I would like to reach effect that on click this button it redirects to external URL, eg. http://google.com. I don't know Angular. Can you help me?
When I click a button it moves to `/home/users`. 
When I replace `url : /dogs` it moves to `/home/dogs`. As you can see, it appends suffix.

How to force not appending (in order to make it possible move to `google`)

Answer (score 1):

In your view, bind the click event to a component method :

```
<button (click)="openUrl('www.google.com')">button</button>
```

And in your component use `window.location.href` to make the redirection:

```
openUrl(siteWeb: string) {

    let link = siteWeb;

    let httpPrefix = "http://";
    if (!siteWeb.startsWith(httpPrefix)) {
      link = httpPrefix + siteWeb
    }

    window.location.href = link;
  }
```

**Note** : Your link must be prefixed with `http://` to make an external navigation.

Comment: I would like to use my current apporach - it means that buttons are connected to modules, modules define state.

Comment: What do you mean by buttons are connected to modules ? What do you call module ?